# Retrieve message history from Viber PC version

Tags: window, history, viber

I was using Viber in both PC (window 7) and Mobile phone. application on my phone and pc has been reinstalled. i cannot retrieve the message history on the viber application for pc. Good thing i have backup copy of the viber messages in my pc viber.db ... I need to retrieve message history for future needs (date , time, mobile no, messages).
Hope some one can help. really desperate

What I have tried so far:
select timestamp, chattoken, body from eventinfo order by number

But the timestamp is in int not on date format

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch'), chattoken, body from eventinfo order by timestamp;
```

You can have a look at ["SQL As Understood By SQLite"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more information about date functions.